# Path to theme within a module / jQuery context?

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I've written a custom D7 module as a companion to a theme I've contributed to drupal.org and in the module, I effect output of the logo image with some basic jQuery as such:

```
$("li.purple").click(function () {
$('#logo-img').attr('src', '/sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/logo-purple.png');
});

$("li.green").click(function () {
$('#logo-img').attr('src', '/sites/all/themes/mytheme/images/logo-green.png');
});
```

etc...

Now this works fine but ideally I'd like not to have to hard code the theme path as above, it would be great to have a variable instead.

I did some searching and found a drupal docs page, "[Pass the theme path to javascript](https://drupal.org/node/1427564)", but I can't really make heads or tails of it within the context of what I'm trying to do. There's a preprocess function on the aforementioned docs page that supposedly can tell jQuery what the path to the theme is but I don't quiet understand the usage in terms of actually creating a theme path variable.  So from this:

```
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_js('jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "pathToTheme": "' . path_to_theme() . '" });', 'inline');
}
```

I need to extract the path variable and put into this:

```
$("li.green").click(function () {
$('#logo-img').attr('src', pathToTheme + '/images/logo-purple.png');
});
```

... However, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pathToTheme is not defined
```

... so I'm just struggling how to get this to work or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Drupal.settings.pathToTheme`.

```
$("li.green").click(function () {
 $('#logo-img').attr('src', Drupal.settings.pathToTheme + '/images/logo-purple.png');
});
```

Also, `theme_preprocess_page(&$vars)` should be in template.php as `your_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars)`;

Good idea to not hard code the theme path, that path structure wouldn't work for all set-ups.

Comment: Ah, perfect, I ended up doing `$('#logo-img').attr('src', '/' + Drupal.settings.pathToTheme + '/images/logo-purple.png');` with the forward slash in front of the path. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  The `/` may cause problems on some set-ups as well, I believe (though I can't think of specific cases right now). Just keep in mind that you also have `Drupal.settings.basePath`

Comment: So I should probably combine `Drupal.settings.basePath` with `Drupal.settings.pathToTheme` so I don't need to hard code the forward slash I am guessing? I'll have to test that out. Thanks.

Comment: It worked, I did: `$('#logo-img').attr('src', Drupal.settings.basePath + Drupal.settings.pathToTheme + '/images/logo.png');`

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think that building up paths in JS should be avoided.  I used to do this, but lately, run into the problem that can result.

When you glue together a path in JS, you bypass the API.  In your particular example, it would mean that your image couldn't be server up from a CDN.

I would do something like

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page (&variables) {
  $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME');

  drupal_add_js(array(
    'MYTHEME' => array(
      'logoSrc' => file_create_url($path . '/images/logo.png'),
    ),
  ), 'setting');
}
```

in your theme, and then in your JS

```
$("li.green").click(function () {
  $('#logo-img').attr('src', Drupal.settings.MYTHEME.logoSrc);
});
```

Also note that in the [Drupal Javascript API](https://drupal.org/node/751744), the jQuery context and settings are passed into behaviors, so you can do something like:

```
(function ($, Drupal, undefined) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MYTHEME = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $("li.green", context).click(function () {
        $('#logo-img', context).attr('src', settings.MYTHEME.logoSrc);
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

in your theme Javascript.

Comment: Interesting, I'm also setting a jQuery cookie when a color is clicked so I'd presume I can possibly do this with one of your examples above. I'll check these out, I'm all for doing things the proper drupal way. Thank you!